# $injector:modulerr : when trying to run my application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing my first app using angular. but getting **$injector:modulerr** error. I am very much confused . could anybody tell me what am i doing wrong here?
 I have inititalised using ng-app = "starApp". then initialised my module in app.js

my HTML code-

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html ng-app="starApp">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <title>MY DEMO</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link href="app-content/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   </head>
  <body ng-controller = "LoginController">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="app-services/authentication.service.js"></script>
<script src="app-services/flash.service.js"></script>

<!-- Real user service that uses an api -->
 <script src="app-services/user.service.js"></script>

<!-- Fake user service for demo that uses local storage -->
<script src="app-services/user.service.local-storage.js"></script>

<script src="home/home.controller.js"></script>
<script src="login/login.controller.js"></script>
<script src="register/register.controller.js"></script>
```

my config.js-

```
   'use strict';

   var starApp = angular.module("starApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);
   // Main app config
   starApp.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    '$sceDelegateProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    '$httpProvider',

    function($routeProvider, $sceDelegateProvider, $locationProvider,
            $httpProvider, $compileProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            controller : 'HomeController',
            templateUrl : 'home/home.view.html',
            controllerAs : 'vm'
        }).when('/login', {
            controller : 'LoginController',
            templateUrl : 'login/login.view.html',
            controllerAs : 'vm'
        })

        .when('/register', {
            controller : 'RegisterController',
            templateUrl : 'register/register.view.html',
            controllerAs : 'vm'
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/login'
        });
    }]);
```

My controller where i tried to put business logic for my login page-

```
      (function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('starApp').controller('LoginController', LoginController);

LoginController.$inject = ['$location', 'AuthenticationService',
        'FlashService'];
function LoginController($location, AuthenticationService, FlashService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.login = login;

    (function initController() {
        // reset login status
        AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
    })();

    function login() {
        vm.dataLoading = true;
        AuthenticationService.Login(vm.username, vm.password, function(
                response) {
            if (response.success) {
                AuthenticationService.SetCredentials(vm.username,
                        vm.password);
                $location.path('/');
            } else {
                FlashService.Error(response.message);
                vm.dataLoading = false;
            }
        });
    };
}

 })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a mismatch of injection arguments in `.config`. There are 4 strings but 5 arguments in function. If you aren't using`$compileProvider` in config remove it as an argument or else add it to strings

Answer (score 0):

Have you included config.js in your html.